# How to re-deploy to tomcat without re-building the application

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am building a web application using Intellij IDEA and I deploy the application to tomcat using a run configuration which uses tomcat7 maven plugin goal `tomcat7:run`.

When testing the app, I sometimes need to redeploy the app even without a change in the application to re-do some initialization work which happens in the deployment.

If I use same run configuration (maven goal `tomcat7:run`), the project gets re-built and it takes a considerable amount of time. Is there a way I can redeploy the app through IDEA without building it again?

Comment: Undeploy and redeploy?

Comment: Redeploying didn't give me the output of tomcat in IDEA output pane. tomcat7:run-war-only did what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple logic. **If you don't need re-build, You will don't need re-deploy.** Only case new [deploy](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html).